# Unable to generate Ed25519 Key

Tags: ssh-keys

FYI..this is the first time I'm generating/upgrading any key. It may happen that my question sounds silly , so sorry for that.

I'm referring https://medium.com/risan/upgrade-your-ssh-key-to-ed25519-c6e8d60d3c54 doc for Ed25519 key generation. However, when I run:

```
    ssh-keygen -o -a 100 -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -C "test key"
```

I get below error:

```
    unknown option -- o
```

By, referring some other documents on internet, I tried by skipping -o option. Then, I got "unknown key type error":

```
     ssh-keygen  -a 100 -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -C "test key"
     unknown key type ed25519
```

Is there anything else , I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance!